# Need guidance starting node js / scala app

Tags: linux, installation, node.js, development, scala

I have installed yum/apt-get installed scala, "node install" installed gulp, but cannot find how to run it for dev mode. I have started a number of node applications in the past.

I am trying to start this app for development (I want to play with the the UI)
 https://github.com/ornicar/lila

FTA: "You're welcome to reuse as much code as you want for your projects"

Thanks for any guidance here

Comment: So you want to contribute [lichess](http://en.lichess.org/) ?

Comment: of course. In such a way that allows me to launch at least the UI (lesser attention on game engine) on my dev server.

Comment: Do you have good knowledge in Scala and NodeJS ? *You just recently installed Scala*

Comment: I am looking for help starting this. I have started & learned from many node apps while learning javascript.

Comment: So man I advise you not to hurry. First of all improve your skills. If you want I can post answer for how getting good start with NodeJS or Scala...

Comment: please do post .

Comment: Can you provide response on my answer ? *If my answer is not helpful for you I just delete it*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I advice you explore languages and tools that you want to learn. If it's programming language what paradigm is support what kind of problem this lang solve and so on...

### Scala

- to getting start read [wiki post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language))
- [Twitter Scala school](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/)
- [Scala on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun)
- and the same time read this **[book](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)**

*Actually before pick up Scala will good have good knowledges in the Java*

### NodeJS

Before dive in NodeJS you **must** have good experience with JavaScript

- [Node API](https://nodejs.org/api/)
- [Node.js Tutorial – Step-by-Step Guide For Getting Started](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/node-js-tutorial)
- you mentioned about Gulp.js, this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLnpHn493BHE2RsdyUNpbiVn-cfuV7Fos) will nice for learning it quickly

NodeJS platform provide opportunity create Web app on pure JavaScript this third party libraries as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) or [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)